# strcat concat a char onto a string?

Tags: c, string, char, concatenation, strcat

Using GDB, I find I get a segmentation fault when I attempt this operation:

```
strcat(string,&currentChar);
```

Given that string is initialized as

```
char * string = "";
```

and currentChar is

```
char currentChar = 'B';
```

Why does this result in a segmentation fault?

If strcat can't be used for this, how else can I concat a char onto a string?

Comment: strcat requires null-terminated strings. Your single char has no null, so strcat will keep copying until it finds a null somewhere down the line, which could be on the 2nd byte by accident, or a few gigabytes down the road, all the while copying all that garbage into your string, stomping on the stack

Comment: char * string = "";  does not reserve any space for concatenation, and is usually placed in RODATA program segment, not writable. Declare and define string this way: char string[80] = ""; to reserve an 80ch buffer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Because `&currentChar` is not a string, it doesn't finish with `\0` character. You should define `B` as `char *currentChar = 'B';`. Also according to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat `string` should have enough space to hold the result string (2 bytes in this case), but it is only 1 byte.

Or if you want to use `char` then you can do something like (depending of your code):

```
char string[256];
...

char currentChar = 'B';
size_t cur_len = strlen(string);
if(cur_len < 254) {
    string[cur_len] = currentChar;
    string[cur_len+1] = '\0';
}
else
    printf("Not enough space");
```

Comment: Not the reason why the program is segfaulting.  This is part of the error though

Comment: @Foo `&currentChar` doesn't point on null terminates string and of course strcpy will cause a seg fault

Comment: I accepting this as the answer because it covers that A: I needed the null terminators, and B: I had to allocate more space for string.

Comment: string[cur_len+1] should be set to 0, not '\n'

Answer (score 18):

As responded by others, *&currentChar* is a pointer to **char** or **char***, but a string in C is **char[]** or **const char***.

One way to use strcat to concatenate a **char** to **string** is creating a minimum string and use it to transform a char into string.

**Example:**

Making a simple string, with only 1 character and the suffix **'\0'**;

```
char cToStr[2];
cToStr[1] = '\0';
```

Applying to your question:

```
char * string = "";
char currentChar = 'B';
```

cToStr will assume the string "B":

```
cToStr[0] = currentChar;
```

And strcat will work!

```
strcat ( string, cToStr );
```

Answer (score 3):

I think the simplest method (not efficient) would be `sprintf`

`sprintf(str, "%s%c", str, chr);`

Comment: why is not efficient?

Comment: @GustavoAdolfoMejía because it has to parse the format string. You can write your own function (say `strcatchar()`) to do the same job more efficiently.

Comment: Also with some compiler you would get a warning: passing argument 1 to restrict-qualified parameter aliases with argument 3

Comment: This code has undefined behavior because you cannot use the destination array as the source for a `%s` conversion.

Comment: [**7.21.6.6 The sprintf function**. paragraph 2](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.6p2): "If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined."

Answer (score 2):

strcat() takes two '\0'-terminated strings. When you pass the address of a character, the routine will look at the memory that follows the character, looking for the terminator.

Since you don't know what that memory even refers to, you should expect problems when your code accesses it.

In addition to that, your string argument does not have room to have any characters appended to it. Where is that memory written to? It will attempt to write past the end of the memory associated with this string.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the strings must be null-terminated. A single char isn't null terminated, so it's undefined when strcat will stop concatenating characters to the end. Also, string must contain at least enough space for both the original string and resultant string.

This works:

```
char string[10] = "";
char* currentChar = "B";
strcat(string, currentChar);
```

Comment: This does not work because there is not enough space in string.  To see my point, try it: http://ideone.com/0jjST

Comment: There's two problems with the code. The first argument doesn't have enough space, the second one has no terminator. Why are you focused on only one issue?

Comment: it's part of the reason, though you're right it's not the main one. fixed to include the main cause of the segfault

Answer (score 0):

We know that currentChar = 'B'.

This can be done

```
strcat(string, "B");
```

If we know currentChar will be hardcoded as 'B', this would be a good approach.

It also removes the need for char currentChar = 'B';

Comment: Why add a redundant `\0` in the string literal? Just write `strcat(string, "B");`

Comment: I don't remember but strcat does add the `\0` by default to the end of the string so there isn't a need for it. I've updated it, thanks @chqrlie!

Comment: `strcat` always appends a null terminator. The `\0` was redundant because `"B"` already has one (it is an array of 2 `char` including the null terminator) whereas `"B\0"` is an array of 3 `char` with 2 null bytes at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Make your own function.

```
void strcatc(char *s, char c) {
    while (*s != 0) s++;
    *s++ = c;
    *s = 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `strcat()` to append a character to a string, the second argument must be a pointer to a null terminated array of `char` (a C string), but you can use `strncat`:

```
    strncat(string, &currentChar, 1);
```

This use of `strncat` is rather unconventional but does meet the goal.

Here is the specification of this seldom used standard C library function:

> **7.26.3.2 The strncat function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> #include <string.h>
> char *strncat(char * restrict s1, const char * restrict s2, size_t n);
> ```
>
> The `strncat` function appends not more than `n` characters (a null character and characters that follow it are not appended) from the array pointed to by `s2` to the end of the string pointed to by `s1`. The initial character of `s2` overwrites the null character at the end of `s1`. A terminating null character is always appended to the result.<sup>378)</sup> If copying takes place between objects that overlap, the behavior is undefined.
>
> **Returns**
>
> The `strncat` function returns the value of `s1`.
>
> ---
>
> <sub><sup>378)</sup>Thus, the maximum number of characters that can end up in the array pointed to by `s1` is `strlen(s1)+n+1`.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

The first argument of strcat must have enough space to hold the rest of the string. "" is a constant string and as such GCC does not allocate space.

Make it an array with enough space:

```
char buf[1024];

strcpy(buf, "");
strcat(buf, "B");
```