# How to read a line from a read-only FIFO in C?

Tags: c, fifo

I've got a problem reading a couple of lines from a read-only FIFO. In particular, I have to read two lines — a number `n`, followed by a `\n` and a string `str` — and my C program should write `str` in a write-only FIFO for `n` times. This is my attempt.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readline(int fd);

int main(int  argc, char** argv) {
    int in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    mkfifo(argv[2], 0666);
    int out = open(argv[2] ,O_WRONLY);
    char *line = (char *) malloc(50);
    int n;

    while (1) {
        sscanf(readline(in), "%d", &n);
        strcpy(line, readline(in));

        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            write(out, line, strlen(line));
            write(out, "\n", 1);
        }
    }

    close(in);
    close(out);
    return 0;
}

char *readline(int fd) {
    char *c = (char *) malloc(1);
    char line[50];

    while (read(fd, c, 1) != 0) {
        if (strcmp(c, "\n") == 0) { 
            break;
        }
        strcat(line, c);
    }
    return line;
}
```

The code is working properly, but it puts a random number of newlines after the last string repetition. Also, this number changes at each execution.

Could someone please give me any help?

Comment: `char *c = (char *) malloc(1);` a 1 char buffer will not have enough place for a character plus a null terminator; the `strcat(line, c);` will expect its arguments both to be nul-terminated.

Comment: And don't cast malloc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your code did not work on my machine, and I'd say you're lucky to get any meaningful results at all.

Here are some problems to consider:

- `readline` returns a locally defined static char buffer (`line`), which will be destroyed when the function ends and the memory it once occupied will be free to be overwritten by other operations.
- If `line` was not set to null bytes on allocation, `strcat` would treat its garbage values as characters, and could possibly try to write after its end.
- You allocate a 1-byte buffer (`c`), I suspect, just because you need a char* in `read`. This is unnecessary (see the code below). What's worse, you do not deallocate it before `readline` exits, and so it leaks memory.
- The `while(1)` loop would re-read the file and re-print it to the output fifo until the end of time.
- You're using some "heavy artillery" - namely, `strcat` and memory allocation - where there are simpler approaches.
- Last, some C standard versions may require that you declare all your variables before using them. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8474100/where-you-can-and-cannot-declare-new-variables-in-c).

And here's how I modified your code. Note that, if the second line is longer than 50 characters, this code may also not behave well. There are techniques around the buffer limit, but I don't use any in this example:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

char *readline(int fd, char * buffer);

int main(int  argc, char** argv) {
    int in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
    int out;
    int n;
    int i;
    char line[50];

    memset(line, 0, 50);
    mkfifo(argv[2], 0666);
    out = open(argv[2] ,O_WRONLY);

    sscanf(readline(in, line), "%d", &n);
    strcpy(line, readline(in, line));

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        write(out, line, strlen(line));
        write(out, "\n", 1);
    }

    close(in);
    close(out);
    return 0;
}

char *readline(int fd, char * buffer) {
    char c;
    int counter = 0;
    while (read(fd, &c, 1) != 0) {
        if (c == '\n') {
            break;
        }
        buffer[counter++] = c;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

This works on my box as you described. Compiled with GCC 4.8.2 .

Comment: Thank you, this works fine for me, too. I just only got a last question: how can the write-only FIFO be opened _before_ its creation with `mkfifo`?

Comment: What do you mean by "before"? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Well, I suppose that the `out` FIFO doesn't exist after its creation with `mkfifo(argv[2], 0666)`, so I wonder how I can open it earlier (i. e. the `open` call comes first). Sorry, this might seem a stupid question for you, but I'm pretty new to FIFOs and I had to make a big effort to understand them.

Comment: Oh, I had an error trying to access a named pipe before creating it. Only reason it worked was a named pipe left over from the previous run - edited. That was what you were asking, right?

Answer (score 1):

Besides the facts that reading character wise and and comparing two characters using "string" comparsion both is far from being efficient, `readline()` returns a pointer to memory being declared local to `readline()`, that is `line[50]` The memory gets deallocated as soon as `readline()` returns, so accessing it afterwards invokes undefine behaviour.

One possibility to fix this is to declare the buffer to read the line into outside `readline()` and pass a reference to it down like so:

```
char * readline(int fd, char * line, size_t size) 
{
  if ((NULL != line) && (0 < size))
  {
    char c = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    while (read(fd, &c, 1) >0) 
    {
      if ('\n' == c) or (size < i) { 
        break;
      }
      line[i] = c;
      ++i;
    }
    line [i] = 0;
  }

  return line;
}
```

And then call it like this:

```
char * readline(int fd, char * line, size_t size);

int main(void)
{
  ...
  char line[50] = "";
  ...
  ... readline(in, line, sizeof(line) - 1) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried running your code, but in your `readline` function you have not terminated the `line` with null (`'\0'`) character. once you hit `'\n'` character you just breaking the `while` loop and returning the string `line`. Try adding `'\0'` character before returning from the function `readline`.

Click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834811/strcat-concat-a-char-onto-a-string) for more info.